ValueError: `to_quantize` can only either be a keras Sequential or Functional model
I'm currently learning TinyML with Tensorflow Lite and Tensorflow Lite for Micro.
I'm working with the book "Hands-on TinyML" from R. Banerjee.
I'm trying to quantize a model but it generated the error:
q_aware_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_model(basemodel)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tensorflow_model_optimization/python/core/quantization/keras/quantize.py:135 in quantize_model
raise ValueError(
ValueError: to_quantize can only either be a keras Sequential or Functional model.
This is the Python source of my exercice:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dropout, Dense

def base_model():

  model = Sequential()      
  model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape = (28,28,1)))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  model.add(Dense(100, activation = "relu"))
  model.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
  
  return model

basemodel = base_model()
basemodel.summary()

import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot

quantized_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_model

# q_aware stands for for quantization aware.
q_aware_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_model(basemodel)

# `quantize_model` requires a recompile.
q_aware_model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

q_aware_model.summary()

The raised error is at line:

q_aware_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_model(basemodel)

I don't know why.
Could you please help me?
My environment: spyder 5.5.6,Python 3.12.6 64-bit, tensorflow 2.17.0, tensorflow-model-optimization 0.8.0, keras 3.5.0.

I solved myself the problem by rewriting th AI model like:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dropout, Dense
from tensorflow_model_optimization.python.core.keras.compat import keras
#import tf_keras as keras

def base_model():

  model = keras.Sequential([
  keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape = (28,28,1)),
  keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
  keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
  keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
  keras.layers.Flatten(),
  keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
  keras.layers.Dense(100, activation = "relu"),
  keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax") 
])
  
  return model

basemodel = base_model()
basemodel.summary()

import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot

quantized_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_model

# q_aware stands for for quantization aware.
q_aware_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_model(basemodel)

# `quantize_model` requires a recompile.
q_aware_model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

q_aware_model.summary()

Thanks.
Eddy33
